# How to create a drive rest app using codenighter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I want to create an Android Google Drive App which has a function to upload files to google drive from my app using Codenighter as backend. I am very new to Codenighter. I had went through the official documentation and got the following [PHP quickstart for Google drive v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/php)

I had done following steps:

1. I had created a Create a project and enabled the Google Drive API
2. Configured OAuth consent screen and created credentials
3. Downloaded credentials.json and copied it to my project root directory

Finally, I had created a controller as shown below

```
<?PHP
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
define('STDIN',fopen("php://stdin","r"));

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

/**
 * Index Page for this controller.
 *
 * Maps to the following URL
 *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
 *  - or -
 *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
 *  - or -
 * Since this controller is set as the default controller in
 * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
 *
 * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
 * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
 * @see https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
 */
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('welcome_message');
}

public function getClient(){
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google Drive API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);
    $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

    // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    $tokenPath = 'token.json';
    if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }

    // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        } else {
            // Request authorization from the user.
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            print 'Enter verification code: ';
            $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

            // Check to see if there was an error.
            if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
            }
        }
        // Save the token to a file.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
      $client = getClient();
    $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

    // Print the names and IDs for up to 10 files.
    $optParams = array(
    'pageSize' => 10,
    'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)'
    );
    $results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);

    if (count($results->getFiles()) == 0) {
        print "No files found.\n";
    } else {
        print "Files:\n";
        foreach ($results->getFiles() as $file) {
            printf("%s (%s)\n", $file->getName(), $file->getId());
        }
    }
}

}
```

I had created two functions such as view files and getClient. getClient has generated a token if not already exist and to view the files in the google drive which I have authenticated. I don't know exactly where to keep this getClient() and how to get that client very time. All I want is whenever I am uploading file to google drive, I also want to check whether the token expired or not. If expired I want to generate new one.So what I have to do?

When I am running the above code, I am getting an error like this

Open the following link in your browser: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&access_type=offline&client_id=751215721134-94mfvkjlt7nkt5296q640qcj3q96e0fk.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Foauthplayground&state&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive.metadata.readonly&prompt=select_account%20consent Enter verification code: An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: InvalidArgumentException Message: Invalid code Filename: /home/ua5r3kd1on8p/public_html/GDriveApp/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php Line Number: 178 Backtrace: File: /home/ua5r3kd1on8p/public_html/GDriveApp/application/controllers/Welcome.php Line: 59 Function: fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode File: /home/ua5r3kd1on8p/public_html/GDriveApp/index.php Line: 318 Function: require_once

How to resolve this?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to read the code and the inline comments.  It explains what the code does.  Are you looking for a more in depth expiation of how the client library works?

Comment: @DalmTo Currently, I want to upload files and get an id that uniquely identifies files in the drive. Then I will store it in the database and based on the id I want to download the files from google drive.

Comment: Are you aware that the file id is not static and it may change over time?   Here is a sample for download [large-file-download.php](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/large-file-download.php)

Comment: One last note about your code remember its for an installed app it wont work hosted on a website.

Comment: @DaImTo it won't change right. Actually, I had implemented this in java. I haven't been notified ever as id changed.

Comment: @DaImTo i had run it in the  server i got the URL to select mail but I am getting an error like this,   Enter verification code: An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: InvalidArgumentException Message: Invalid code Filename: /home/ua5r3kd1on8p/public_html/GDriveApp/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php Line Number: 178 Backtrace: File: /home/ua5r3kd1on8p/public_html/GDriveApp/application/controllers/Welcome.php Line: 59 Function: fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode File: /home/ua5r3kd1on8p/public_html/GDriveApp/index.php Line: 318 Function: require_once

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239390/discussion-between-linet-m-shaji-and-daimto).

Comment: You understand this code is for an installed application. Its not designed to run hosted on a web server.
It actually states that at the top of the tutorial **Complete the steps described in the rest of this page to create a simple PHP command-line application that makes requests to the Drive API.**   That code is also single user so if you want more then one user your not going to be able to use that code.

Comment: hello there @LinetMShaji, would you providing more information about what exactly are you trying to achieve? what type of credentials are you using? did you authorize the app and used the code required? moreover, the snippet you have shared is already dealing with the authorization part

Comment: @ale13 This is all about, I want to create an android app with the functionality users which registered with the app should be able to upload their personal documents to the drive. So here I will use one Gmail account to authorize with GDrive and I want to upload all documents to that authorized Gmail account. That's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't know exactly where to keep this getClient() and how to get that client very time.

Im not exactly sure what you mean.  The getClient method should be part of your code  always. Your code needs $client to create the Drive service object which is used to access all the apis.  Without client being loaded properly with your refresh token and access token the drive service object wont work.

> I also want to check whether the token expired or not. If expired I want to generate new one.So what I have to do?

Your code is already doing that.  If the access token currently stored in $client has expired then it will use the refresh token to request a new one

```
// If there is no previous token or it's expired.
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
    if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
```

Comment: @DalmTo So how to get this client if I am writing a separate function for viewing files. If I have more than a function means it is not good to write token generation code in every function right. That's why I mentioned I don't know to keep this getClient code.

Comment: Then put it in a file on its own and include it in your project.  [include](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)   You understand though that the Google drive api is a file storage api it cant help you "view" files.